# Restoring MySQL files to new disk 14.04 - permissions?

Tags: mysql, 14.04

I am rebuilding my computer with a new disk and have a backup of my MySQL db's - I have moved them to /var/lib/mysql and when I try:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

MySQL refuses to start - the error log shows this error below. I am assuming my perms on /var/lib/mysql are wrong but am unsure how to proceed.

```
140421 12:03:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140421 12:03:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140421 12:03:59 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140421 12:03:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140421 12:03:59 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140421 12:03:59  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

Many thanks...

Comment: This seems to work for me - I'm guessing it's appropriate? 

    `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/`

I do still get an error on start though (db's are there and visible) .. 

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 1):

Permissions (ownership, specifically) may be an issue, in which case they can be corrected to the default by doing:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Obviously, change the username (the first mysql in that command) and the group (the second) if you've edited your user/group that MySQL runs as.

However, I'd like to note that backing up the raw files is generally discouraged when migrating. Using the mysqldump command is generally preferred, as it outputs to a text file using SQL which can be imported and executed cleanly by the new version.

Between 12.04 and 14.04, you probably won't see too many issues, but more dramatic changes can sometimes be a problem. For instance, in some past upgrades, the way that usernames were hashed changed dramatically, and using older raw files required a special config option that could not be resolved without using special tools or commands.

Comment: Thanks @k-darien-freeheart ! This is precisely how I resolve a similar issue on my end in the mysql Docker container. Somehow the permissions were off, fixing them all to `mysql:mysql` did the trick! Glad that I recovered all the data. Btw, apparently `restorecon -R /var/lib/mysql/` or `chcon -R --type=mysql_db_t /var/lib/mysql` did not work for Ubuntu based distro.

Comment: That's correct. Those commands for for SELinux, which Ubuntu doesn't use. 

Ubuntu uses AppArmor for additional security contexts.